# Converting MySQL datetime to RFC 2822 Using PHP date() Function

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm setting up PHP's if-modified-since header on our webpages.  I can detect if a php file has been saved and then properly set the header using PHP's filetime() and date() functions.  However I also need to properly set the header when information in the database that gets displayed on the php page changes.

For the file being changed I use PHP's date() function like so:

```
date("r", $file_mod)
```

However when I use it on what I get from querying a MySQL datetime field, I always get the following response where the date, time, year, and month are wrong:

```
Wed, 31 Dec 1969 18:33:30 -0600
```

What is the proper way to convert from MySQL's datetime to RFC 2822, or at least how do I convert to a format to put into PHP's date() function to get the correct response?

Comment: MySQL doesn't store the timezone with any of it's temporal data types, nor does its [date formatting support placeholders to list it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(exampledate,'%a, %d %b %Y %T') // given a MySQL datetime

date('r') // for PHP
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using MySQL's [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function in your query. That way the date will arrive in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Check youre timezone settings

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

functions like date() depend on these settings.

Answer (score -2):

[strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) will do the job

If you don't mind, I'd like to see your implementation of "if-modified-since".  I need to do that on one of my sites.